# public virtual delegate void not allowed

Tags: c#, abstract-class

Well I thought of creating a common Base class for a growing group of different camera hardware so future projects could stick to a common wrapper pattern; and more easily switch camera types. So I wrote:

```
NameSpace Wrapper
{ 
public class BaseCamera
{
    public virtual event FrameArivedEventHandler FrameArived; //seams fine
    public virtual delegate void FrameArivedEventHandler(object sender, FrameArivedEventArgs e); //errors
    public virtual class FrameArivedEventArgs : EventArgs   //event class variabelen.
    {
        public int counter;
        public byte[] RawRGB;
    }
```

But I got a warning "the modifier virtual is not valid on this item",
at the delegate void line, the idea was that for each camera class, I would like to use this Base class and overwrite specific methods (for example a depth camera contains a public usort[ ] depth; Where is a heat cam may contain a list of double and return also max heat in the frame data.

Not sure why I get the error cause it seams in some WIP code (not an executable) I don't get these warning (the WIP code rather outlined the class model before putting in specific project).

Now I wonder isn't it really allowed, or can it be done but i do something wrong here?.

Comment: The `delegate` keyword is a **type** declaration. `FrameArivedEventHanlder` is a _class_ inherited from `Delegate`. Types cannot be `virtual`.

Answer (score 1):

The way you want to do this is a bit walking around. Did you try to write some real life example that it would be used in the end (e.g. some test)?

Delegate is a kind of type and you cannot override it (or even inherit from it).

I think that you should consider event as something same for all camera types, what can change is EventArgs or handling events.

I have made a little example with generics and simple implementation, please take a look if this is what you want to do.

```
public abstract class BaseCamera<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public delegate void FrameArivedEventHandler(object sender, TEventArgs e); //errors

    public virtual event FrameArivedEventHandler FrameArivedEvent; //seams fine

    protected void Trigger(TEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        FrameArivedEvent(this, eventArgs);
    }
}

public abstract class FrameArivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int counter;
    public byte[] RawRGB;
}

public class NikonCamera : BaseCamera<NikonFrameArrivedEventArgs>
{
    public override event FrameArivedEventHandler FrameArivedEvent
    {
        // Override whatever
        add => base.FrameArivedEvent += value;
        remove => base.FrameArivedEvent -= value;
    }
}

public class NikonFrameArrivedEventArgs : FrameArivedEventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class TestExampleUsageClass
{

    public TestExampleUsageClass()
    {
        var camera = new NikonCamera();
        camera.FrameArivedEvent += MyTestClassFrameArrivedEventHandler;
    }

    private void MyTestClassFrameArrivedEventHandler(object sender, NikonFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the real life usage would be that i endup with a general way in my code to deal with various camera's. Industrial camera's are often quite complex to configure, and setup, which makes it complex to re-use code, or quickly change camera's for an existing project. Some return RGB others YUV or Ushort Double etc

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error

```
 public virtual delegate void 
FrameArivedEventHandler(object sender, FrameArivedEventArgs e); //errors
```

because you are marking delegate as virtual , and using that delegate type on your event.

one more thing if you are creating abstract class then you methods are `abstract` not virtual , right now you are having normal class with virtual methods.

And bigger issue with you code is `public virtual delegate` , you delegate is public that means its modifiable and cause issue for you. to understand this more check here : [Event Vs Deleagte](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2016/03/event-vs-deleagte.html)

---

```
public virtual class FrameArivedEventArgs : EventArgs
```

In C# you cannot have virtual class , that is also wrong. it should be `abstract`

Comment: hm, so types stay types they're not overriden, but 
i tought to create virtual methods and the use override functions in specific camera classes.

Comment: @user3800527 - not getting you much but if you are having event , then in deriving class you should implment function and attach with that event..not getting purpose of making delegate virtual

Comment: isnt it possible to re-define an event ?, ea keeping the same name, but reurn something different (byte [ ]  RGB /instead of / int [ ] depth )

Comment: @user3800527 - no , event allows us to bind function of given delegate type , i havent seen some one to overriding event ...you are all together on wrong path , you should better get idea about event/delegate in much detail

Comment: :) your right, i got a bit overwhelmed because of the huge differences in vendor specific code how each handles their camera data. I'm not going to re-define event classes, instead i will make general Base for their data events ea ( YUV, RGB Flir, TOF, IR, etc) the Base class can contain them, and its up to derived classes to fill / trigger what they support.